# What permission restricts access to run updates in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, updating

I have a role in my Drupal site that I don't want to access the Drupal database updates.  I can't seem to find the permission for "Run updates".  What permission restricts access to this page (update.php)?

Answer (score 3):

The permission is **Administer software updates**

[image]

Comment: Check out `update_access_allowed()` in update.php for how this works.

Comment: Hmmm. I've logged in with the autenticated user role that does not have the Administer software updates permission checked but they can still access the update.php page. Also, "Run updates" is showing up as a drop down menu on the home button. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c7O5o.jpg)

Comment: The answer provided is correct. The  permission is Administer software updates.  However, in my case I had the Administration menu module enabled and it seems to ignore that permission by showing Run Updates on its menu.  I had to configure that module to hide the home  button menu as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **settings.php** file and set

```
$update_free_access = FALSE;
```

After doing this only roles that have "Administer software update" permission will be able to see the "Run updates" tab.